# Seeking novel with controls to adjust what other people appear to be wearing

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember what novel a series of scenes came from.  I don't think they played a significant role in the plot, but they were quite memorable nonetheless.

There is a restaurant or nightclub where characters eat several times.  The seating booths are screened in, and there are controls that can be used to adjust the appearance of the people sitting outside; specifically, it changes what they appear to be wearing.

This comes up several times, but one instance is particularly memorable.  One character is there with his mistress, who is fiddling with the controls while they talk.  As she leaves, he spins the control knob, which leaves her nude (although he simulated nudity is apparently not as attractive as the real thing).  Then, after she leaves, the man's estranged wife walks up, equally nude.

What was this from?

Comment: Almost sounds a bit like Douglas Adams (haven't read all his works)

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the early scenes in "Fools" by Pat Cadigan

Comment: Not a restaurant, but it sounds vaguely like the "circuit browsing" scene from *Logan's Run* where Logan 5 first meets Jessica 6. I have only seen the film, so do not know if the *Logan's Run* novel reads similarly.

Answer (score 8):

I saw this again, since it got bumped, and the answer came to me.  I was thinking of *[The Berserker Throne](https://archive.org/details/berserkerthroneb00fred)* by Fred Saberhagen (available online at the link).

[image: The Berserker Throne]

An important scene, about one-third of the way through the book, takes place in the *Contrat Rouge* restaurant of the Templar Radiant space station.  One of the principal protagonists, Prince Harivarman, meets a bunch of other major and minor characters there.  The story was a sequel to (or reimagining of) Saberhagen's 1979 novella "[Some Events at the Templar Radiant](https://archive.org/details/ultimateenemy00saberich)," and among the people Harivarman meets is Greta Thamar, who is identified as the "lover and victim of Georgicus Sabel" in the older story—helping tie the two narratives together.

The walls of the booths at the restaurant have the interesting optical properties I remembered.

Excerpts from the relevant passage (starting on page 102 of the archive.org version linked above):

> Harivarman found Gabrielle waiting for him.  She was fine-tuning the booth's optics absently, so that the images of other patrons and of the human staff came altered through the walls of the plastic enclosure.  The computer system managing the optics identified human images and clothed or re-clothed them to order.  Gabrielle, in a modern green dress as fragile-looking as a spiderweb, currently had everyone who passed the booth dressed in some kind of fancy historical costumes, from a a time and place that Harivarman was unable to identify.
> ...
> The figure of an ethereally lovely human waitress approaching the booth in historical costume turned into the proasic inhuman shape of a robotic waiter as soon as it reached the opening through the walls.
> ...
> Gabrielle had been playing with the optics again, and the Prince did not recognize Colonel Phocion among the giant apes now moving in the aisles past the booth, until the man with drink in hand stopped in the open entrance.
> ...
> She was gone.  He spun the optics control, watching her vary with the optics as she hurried away.  The last spin dealt her nudity, in this case not doing justice to the original.

After his girlfriend Gabrielle leaves, Harivarman's estranged wife Beatrix indeed approaches him.

> But now for some reason she was hurrying back... no, the optics had confused him, this wasn't Gabrielle at all.
>
> Harivarman's heart gave a surprising leap.
>
> He looked up, at close range, to see his wife standing beside the table at which he now sat alone.